# How do I check if an integer is plus or minus 20 of a previously retrieved number.

Tags: objective-c, integer, range

I get a number dynamically in my app every so often and want a method to trigger if the new number is plus or minus 20 than the previous number. Doesn't have to be 20, but just for arguments sake.

First number 100.

Second number 123 > method triggers. Second Number saved.

Third Number 90 > Method Triggers. Third Number saved.

or

First Number 100.

Second number 77 > method triggers. saved

Third Number 80 > method doesn't trigger. saved

Fourth number 101 Method triggers. saved

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Mureinik I tried if(second number +-20) but don't think it works as I am thinking it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the outline of *one* way to give the idea.

You say the allowable difference can change so declare a variable, probably an *instance variable* of an appropriate class, say `maximumDifference` and at an appropriate point set its value:

```
maximumDifference = 20;
```

You also need to remember the last number, so declare a variable for that, again probably an instance variable, say `previousNumber`. At some point you will assign the first number to this:

```
previousNumber = ... first number ...
```

Now when the second and subsequent numbers arrive you need to check if they are outside of the `maximumDifference` of the `previousNumber` and trigger you action, and then update `previousNumber`. You can do the within check either with two comparisons or by using `abs()` function to find the positive difference and comparing that. Here is the outline of the second approach:

```
currentNumber = ... get the next number ...
if( abs(currentNumber - previousNUmber) > maximumDifference )
{
   // do whatever trigger action is required
}
// now update the saved last number
previousNumber = currentNumber;
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little confusing but it sounds like you want to know if the difference between two numbers is more than 20 then you want to trigger something.

Simply do:

```
if (abs(firstNumber - secondNumber) > 20) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the range of the number by adding the following condition:

```
max_Num = previousNum +20;
min_Num = previousNum -20;
if (previousNum >= min_Num && previousNum <= max_Num)
{
    // ...
}
```

Where "20" can be the dynamic number you want